# SSIS Expression task can't see variables populated by a containing foreach loop

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I'm trying to collect a list of file paths from a directory, concatenate them together and then send that value to an execute process task. To do this, I'm using a ForEach loop with an expression task inside that is supposed to stuff the path from each iteration of the loop into a variable. The problem is that when the expression task runs it throws the following error.

```
Error: The type of the value (Empty) being assigned to variable "User::CombinedPath"
differs from the current variable type (String). Variables may not change type
during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.
```

The expression task is basically doing this:

```
@[User::PathFromForEach] + ";"
```

However, it appears that @[User::PathFromForEach] is coming in empty.

What's going on here?

Comment: Well, I was sick for a week, and thought something might happen without me. I guess not. :P

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have set ExecValueVariable property of Expression task to the variable @[User::CombinedPath]. Well, it is not the right place. You need changeExecValueVariable back to None, and write expression as:

```
@[User::CombinedPath]=@[User::PathFromForEach] + ";"
```

Thats it, we only need to use Expression property, nothing else. "**Expression**" property is where the variable actually gets value assigned.. I suppose it would be better to call the property "Assignment" rather than "Expression".